# Ajax upload image without form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, upload, submit

Ok ... I am out of ideas and would need someone to enlight me.

I am trying to upload a file from an INPUT element to a php file (handler.php) using Ajax, and I appear to be missing something. I have spent hours on it and tried many variations, but without success ... I am officially giving in...

i simplified the code to a maximum, can someone tell me what I am missing?

Many Thanks

Here's the script

```
                <script>
                function readURL(fid,input,mxsize,fh,fw) {
                      var form_data = new FormData();
                      form_data.append('img', $('#file_header')[0].files[0]);
                      $.ajax({
                        url:"handler.php",
                        type:"POST",
                        data: form_data,
                        contentType: false,
                        cache: false,
                        processData: false,
                        beforeSend:function(){
                         $('#loader-message-header').html("<label>Image Uploading...</label>");
                         $('#loader-message-header').show();
                        },   
                        success:function(data){
                         alert(data);
                        },
                        fail: function(){
                         $('#loader-message-header').html("<label>Connection to the server lost</label>");
                        }
                      });
               }
            </script>
```

the HTML

```
<form id="register_form" class="mu-reservation-form ">
<input id="file_header" class="file-upload-input" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/*" />
<img class="file-upload-image" src="../assets/img/register/SRP-header.jpg" />
<div id="loader-message-header" class="loader-message"></div>
```

And the CSS

```
.file-upload-input {
                position: absolute;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                outline: none;
                opacity: 0;
                cursor: pointer;
              }

              .image-upload-wrap {
                margin-top: 20px;
                position: relative;
                background-color:#c1a35f;
              }

              .image-upload-wrap:hover{
                opacity: 0.6;
                filter: alpha(opacity=60);
              }
              .loader message{
                display:none; 
              }
```

Comment: what happens or doesn't happen? How do you know you are missing something?  ALSO - the readURL(this) invocation - looks to me like the 'this' is never used. Is that because you were simplifying? Odd to have so many arguments and not touch any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone who will need it on the future.

The code above worked just fine, those damn parse errors got me. Ended-up debugging it successfully.